# Access variable outside jquery each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I've made a each loop that loops through all divs calles opening_class then searches all inputs and saves the value in global openings array.

But.. the openings variable stays empty..

**Javascript**

```
var openings = [];
$('.opening_class').each(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var inputs = [];
    $('.opening_class input').each(function (i) {
        inputs.push($(this).val());
    });
    openings[id] = inputs;
});

alert(JSON.stringify(openings));
```

The inputs has input, but it is not setting it into the global openings array..

If anyone could help that would be awesome

**Html**

```
<div class="row justify-content-between justify-content-center align-content-center opening_class" id="openingstijden">
    <div class="col-3 p-2 text-center font-weight-bold">Maandag:</div>
        <div class="form-group col-4 p-0 m-0">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="openingstijden_ma_1" placeholder="Van" required="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-4 p-0 m-0">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="openingstijden_ma_2" placeholder="Tot" required="">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 p-2 text-center font-weight-bold">Dinsdag:</div>
        <div class="form-group col-4 p-0 m-0">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="openingstijden_di_1" placeholder="Van" required="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-4 p-0 m-0">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="openingstijden_di_2" placeholder="Tot" required="">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 p-2 text-center font-weight-bold">Woensdag:</div>
        <div class="form-group col-4 p-0 m-0">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="openingstijden_wo_1" placeholder="Van" required="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-4 p-0 m-0">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="openingstijden_wo_2" placeholder="Tot" required="">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 p-2 text-center font-weight-bold">Donderdag:</div>
        <div class="form-group col-4 p-0 m-0">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="openingstijden_do_1" placeholder="Van" required="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-4 p-0 m-0">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="openingstijden_do_2" placeholder="Tot" required="">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 p-2 text-center font-weight-bold">Vrijdag:</div>
        <div class="form-group col-4 p-0 m-0">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="openingstijden_vr_1" placeholder="Van" required="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-4 p-0 m-0">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="openingstijden_vr_2" placeholder="Tot" required="">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 p-2 text-center font-weight-bold">Zaterdag:</div>
        <div class="form-group col-4 p-0 m-0">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="openingstijden_za_1" placeholder="Van" required="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-4 p-0 m-0">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="openingstijden_za_2" placeholder="Tot" required="">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 p-2 text-center font-weight-bold">Zondag:</div>
        <div class="form-group col-4 p-0 m-0">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="openingstijden_zo_1" placeholder="Van" required="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-4 p-0 m-0">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="openingstijden_zo_2" placeholder="Tot" required="">
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: provide html too

Comment: is id a number or are you treating an array as an object?

Comment: `$('.opening_class input')` is wrong, you keep selecting al the inputs and not the ones in the section you are looping over

Comment: @AshayMandwarya added html

Comment: @epascarello        var id = $(this).attr('id'); is not a number but string
and 
 inputs.push($(this).val()); is the val of input

Comment: And `$('.opening_class input')` is selecting all the inputs on the page, not the one in the section. And you should be using an object, not an array for openings

Comment: @epascarello       $('.opening_class input').each(function (i) { walks trough all the input fields in opening class, this is working fine.

Because when i alert inputs its showing correctly

Comment: Yes, but if you have more than one `'.opening_class` you are selecting inputs more than once

Comment: change `openings[id] = inputs` to `openings.push(inputs);`

Comment: @epascarello so how to get all inputs from the current opening class then?

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of issues in the code.

needs to be an object, not an array

```
var openings = {};
```

With the following code you are selecting all of the opening class elements and grabbing all the inputs. You are NOT grabbing the inputs inside of the class you read the id for

```
$('.opening_class input').each(function (i) {  // here you are
```

You should be using this and find

```
$(this).find('input').each(function (i) {  // here you are
```

You can also improve your code to use jQuery's map()

```js
var openings = {};
$('.opening_class').each(function() {
  var elem = $(this)
  var id = elem.attr('id');
  var inputs = elem.find('input').map(function(i) {
    return this.value
  }).get();
  openings[id] = inputs;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(openings));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row justify-content-between justify-content-center align-content-center opening_class" id="openingstijden">
  <div class="col-3 p-2 text-center font-weight-bold">Maandag:</div>
  <div class="form-group col-4 p-0 m-0">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="openingstijden_ma_1" placeholder="Van" required="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-4 p-0 m-0">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="openingstijden_ma_2" placeholder="Tot" required="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 p-2 text-center font-weight-bold">Dinsdag:</div>
  <div class="form-group col-4 p-0 m-0">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="openingstijden_di_1" placeholder="Van" required="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-4 p-0 m-0">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="openingstijden_di_2" placeholder="Tot" required="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 p-2 text-center font-weight-bold">Woensdag:</div>
  <div class="form-group col-4 p-0 m-0">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="openingstijden_wo_1" placeholder="Van" required="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-4 p-0 m-0">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="openingstijden_wo_2" placeholder="Tot" required="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 p-2 text-center font-weight-bold">Donderdag:</div>
  <div class="form-group col-4 p-0 m-0">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="openingstijden_do_1" placeholder="Van" required="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-4 p-0 m-0">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="openingstijden_do_2" placeholder="Tot" required="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 p-2 text-center font-weight-bold">Vrijdag:</div>
  <div class="form-group col-4 p-0 m-0">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="openingstijden_vr_1" placeholder="Van" required="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-4 p-0 m-0">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="openingstijden_vr_2" placeholder="Tot" required="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 p-2 text-center font-weight-bold">Zaterdag:</div>
  <div class="form-group col-4 p-0 m-0">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="openingstijden_za_1" placeholder="Van" required="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-4 p-0 m-0">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="openingstijden_za_2" placeholder="Tot" required="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 p-2 text-center font-weight-bold">Zondag:</div>
  <div class="form-group col-4 p-0 m-0">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="openingstijden_zo_1" placeholder="Van" required="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-4 p-0 m-0">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="openingstijden_zo_2" placeholder="Tot" required="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But now the array has {} and [] combined, could this be a problem?

Comment: No clue what the problem is. If would be an object that has keys that are the ids and  it has an array of values.

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. You could simply access the keys of the Object by using `Object.keys(openings)`, or the values by using `Object.values(openings)` to get the arrays.

Comment: @epascarello I plemented it in my EAV model, and it is working lovely thanks!

Answer (score 1):

JS Array cannot contain keys like arrays in php.
You need use

```
var openings = {};
```

Insteadof

```
var openings = [];
```

Comment: Well it can, just not in this use case.